# Avoid sub query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written a mysql query to retrieve data from two tables with subquery and join. 
The query works fine but I want to avoid subquery because of some performance issues.

It should be ordered by date time before group.

```
SELECT a.value1, a.value2, b.value1 FROM (SELECT * FROM A ORDER BY datetime DESC, id DESC) AS a
INNER JOIN B AS b ON b.a_id=a.id
WHERE a.value4="value"
GROUP BY b.value2, b.value3;
```

I have tried several ways to rewrite this without a subquery but still couldn't find a solution.
Is it possible to avoid a sub-query in this case?

Comment: Why You are using sub ?

Comment: Because I want to order A table by datetime before group it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be no purpose to your subquery in the first place. All you are doing is performing an `ORDER BY`, which will be lost the instant you join to the other table. You should be able to do this:

```
SELECT a.value1, a.value2, b.value1 FROM 
    A as a
    INNER JOIN 
    B AS b 
    ON b.a_id=a.id
WHERE a.value4="value"
GROUP BY b.value2, b.value3;
```

Comment: Thanks. But missed the order by.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't got any filter on A table, so you can directly join the table:

```
SELECT b.value2, b.value3 FROM A AS a
INNER JOIN B AS b ON b.a_id=a.id
WHERE a.value4='value'
GROUP BY b.value2, b.value3;
```

Note you have to select columns that were grouped by.

Comment: Thanks. This missed the order by clause in A table.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
SELECT a.value1, a.value2, b.value1 FROM A AS a INNER JOIN B AS b ON b.a_id=a.id WHERE a.value4="value" GROUP BY b.value2, b.value3 ORDER BY a.datetime DESC, a.id DESC;;
```